# How to select out all record when a condition has parent id?

Tags: mysql

The table will like this:

```
 id   content  parent_id  
 1     first      0
 2     second     1
```

question is:
    if if select id = 2 how could i select its parent record within a query

```
   SELECT *
   FROM
      table tb1
   LEFT JOIN
      table tb2
   ON
      tb1.parent_id = tb2.id
   WHERE
      tb1.id = 2
```

when  id = 2 result will return :

```
 1  first  0
 2  second 1
```

not just return :

```
 2 second 1
```

thank u

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT id,content,parent_id FROM table_name 
WHERE (SELECT parent_id FROM table_name WHERE id=2) IN (id,parent_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in your query there is no matching field hence it is returning empty rows!!
in parent_id  change its value from 0,1 to 1,2

by doing that tb2.id=tb1.parent_id will return true and you will get output hope that helps!!